# About the size of unsigned char type in C++

Tags: c++

The standard C++ [3.9.1-1] says that

> For unsigned character types, all possible bit patterns of the value representation represent numbers.

The standard [18.3.2.4-(comment 197)] also says that the maximum value of unsigned char are equivalent to `UCHAR_MAX` in C, which is defined as 255 in C standard [5.2.4.2.1]. So does this mean the size of unsigned char type in C++ is exactly 8 bits?

Comment: Not necessarily. The lowest maximum value of `UCHAR_MAX` is 255, which is an 8-bit `char`. A `char` could be any size, as long as it only uses 1 byte.

Comment: @owacoder no, sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1. However, 1 byte might be bigger than 8 bits. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From C11 5.2.4.2.1

> The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in #if
>   preprocessing directives. Moreover, except for CHAR_BIT and MB_LEN_MAX, the
>   following shall be replaced by expressions that have the same type as would an
>   expression that is an object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer
>   promotions. **Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So the standard defines that at a minimum `UCHAR_MAX` needs to be 255 but it can be greater than that.

The guarantees that we have on size are:

```
sizeof(char) = 1 and sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)
```

And at a minimum the signed versions of the data types must be able to hold:

- `char      [-127, 127]`
- `short     [-32767, 32767]`
- `int       [-32767, 32767]`
- `long      [-2147483647, 2147483647]`
- `long long [-9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775807]`

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I didn't notice these words before the table.

Comment: The *sizes* of the integer types do not necessarily have that relationship. The standard imposes requirements on their ranges (for example `INT_MAX >= SHRT_MAX && INT_MIN <= SHRT_MIN`), but in the presence of padding bits it's at least theoretically  possible to have `sizeof (int) < sizeof (short)`. (This is unlikely in practice.)

Comment: @KeithThompson actually in C++ we have 3.9.1.2 `There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long
long int”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.`

Comment: 'char', 'signed char' and 'unsigned char' are three distinct types, where 'char'      might be signed or unsigned. Hence  'char' has a  range [-128, 127] or {0, 255] (assuming 8 bit)

Comment: @DieterLücking I updated it to say `And at a minimum the signed versions of the data types must be able to hold:` and according to the standard `SCHAR_MIN` is -127 and `SCHAR_MAX` is +127

Comment: @NathanOliver The standard is vague about signed minimal values: It is minus signed_max or less (likely by one).

Comment: @DieterLücking I just figured I should use the figures that are in C11 5.2.4.2.1.1

Comment: @NathanOliver: You're right, my initial comment was based on the C standard; I should have checked the C++ standard. C explicitly permits integer types to have padding bits; C++ doesn't seem to have adopted that (though I don't think it explicitly forbids them). For example a C implementation might have an`int` type occupying 32 bits, but with only 24 of them contributing to the value.

Comment: @KeithThompson I did not know that was allowed in C.  Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: @NathanOliver: See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.2.6.2.