# Why a 8 bit variable got compiled as a 16 bit variable?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I am taking over an old project using TI C2000. Compiled all fine, set break points, stepping through no problem.

Until I found a weird problem today: I defined an `unsigned char` variable, but can get a simple calculation right. I set a break point, and found out compiler made it into a 16 bit variable.

But 8 bit array is compiled as 8 bit no problem.

Screen shot attached here:
[image]

If I treat it as a 16 bit in the software, everything is fine.
But I never run into this type of issue before.

Source code is here:

```
    //check CRC
    unsigned char buf[4];
    unsigned char crc;
    buf[0] = commandWord >> 8;
    buf[1] = commandWord & 0xff;
    buf[2] = data[0] >> 8;
    buf[3] = data[0] & 0xff;
    crc = crc8(buf, 4);

    if (0xf000U == (safetyWord & 0xf000U)) {
        if ((crc & 0x00ff) == (safetyWord & 0x00ff)) {
            ret = TLE_SUCCESS;
        } else {
            ret = -1;
        }
    } else {
        ret = -1;
    }
```

I had to use `crc & 0x00ff` to make the software work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About the size of unsigned char type in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785675/about-the-size-of-unsigned-char-type-in-c)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code but you really need to include a minimal, complete, compilable example. Safetyword isn't defined in the code snippet. What compiler and options are you using?

Comment: Check the size of unsigned char. This could happen if it isn't 8 bits as your code expects. Might well be 16 bits. Unusual, but legal.

Comment: Are you sure `crc8` returns an `unsigned char`? Perhaps it returns a `char` or `signed char` and it's the conversion that borked things.

Comment: There is nothing that guarantees that `unsigned char` is 8 bits (it has to be greater than or equal to 8 bits though)

Comment: DSP cores notoriously march to a different drummer.  This page is pretty good: https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000/f/171/t/317030?Type-Sizes-on-Concerto-cores

Comment: "but can get a simple calculation right."--> Did you mean "but cannot get a simple calculation right."?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

[On this platform](http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000/f/171/t/466647?C2000-integer-size) 1 byte is 16 bits, so `unsigned char` is a 16-bit type.  `buf` is an array of four 16-bit values.

Comment: That explains everything!